# How to cycle OAuth2 client secrets without downtime

Tags: appsec, oauth

I have an app that relies on several OAuth2 providers to poll for background data on behalf of users, as a background process. As a matter of best-practice, I'd like to periodically cycle my client secrets.

The OAuth2 providers I'm using (and every OAuth2 provider I've ever seen) will allow me to re-generate a key/secret pair, but will not allow me to create a second pair.  If I re-generate my secret, there will necessarily be downtime, because the existing key will be invalidated and the app won't know about the new secret yet.

I can't work around this by creating a new OAuth2 relationship, because I would lose all of my permissions to poll data on behalf of my existing users.

How can an application cycle OAuth2 keys without downtime?

Comment: Doesn't the app automatically refresh the short-term token using its long-term secret when it gets an authentication error?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I think you're talking about the access/refresh token pair - the access token is short-lived, and is replaced on expiry.  The refresh token is what permits that replacement.  Both of those are specific to each user, though - as an OAuth2 consumer, I have a secret key that I use to authenticate my whole app.  If my secret is invalidated (by, for example, cycling out keys), then none of my refresh tokens are any good.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've been wondering about as well. I don't think a solution exists right now, but I believe new systems can be designed to do this without downtime by leveraging [Trust Assertions for Certificate Keys](http://tack.io/) (TACK) to do so.

When the client decides to cycle to a new secret we need a mechanism to ensure the server can trust the new secret. In other words, the new secret needs to be signed (i.e. a TACK) by the client. That's what the TACK specification covers, and details a lifecycle for creating a new TACK, revoking, etc. - most importantly it covers the handling of overlapping TACKs so you don't have downtime.